# Why is no data stored in my list in Python?

Tags: python, list, selenium

I have the following code to get some data using selenium. That goes through a list with ids with a for loop and to store them in my lists (`titulos = []` and `ids = []`. It was working fine until I added the try/except. The code would look like this:

```
for item in registros:
   found = False
   ids = []
   titulos = []
   try:
       while true:
       #code to request data
       try:
           error = False
           error = #error message
           if error is True:
                break
       except:
           continue
   except:
      continue
   try:
          found = #if id has data
          if found.is_displayed: 
               titulo = #locator
               ids.append(item)
               titulos.append(titulo)
    except NoSuchElementException:
          input.clear()
```

Comment: Don't use `except: continue`. Raise the exception. We can't tell you exactly what's going on because `# code to request data` is meaningless. An error is being raised, caught, and ignored

Answer (score 0):

The first inner `try` block needs to be indented. Also, the `error` parameter will always be set to the text message so it will always be true. Try formatting your code correctly and then identifying the problem.

Comment: It's already indented. My bad.

Comment: The inner while loop is not properly indented. That's the start of your problems.